# How to sort records with doctrine in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, sql-order-by

I am working on existing project.Getting records something like this:

```
$this->courses = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Course')->findByUserId($this->userId);
```

Now I want to sort above records by User id but I don't know how ?

Is there any solution with this piece of code.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can:

```
$this->courses = Doctrine_Query::create()->from('Course c')->where('c.user_id = ?', $this->userId)->orderBy('c.user_id DESC')->execute();
```